# I want to redirect users directly to my website when user installs my app from Bigcommerce App store..How could I do it?

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to know that how could i create Bigcommerce app in Bigcommerce App Store which redirects users directly to website rather than to open my software in iframe..

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

According to the Bigcommerce requirements for approval of your app, you will need to support the app opening in an iFrame otherwise, your app will not be approved and will not be in the app store. Please check the link below for more details on all the requirements:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/apps/approval-requirements

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have seen some of the Bigcommerce apps like Linnworks,SellerExpress which redirects users to their respective websites directly..Do you have any idea like how did they do that..

Comment: That was from the old app store (V2 of the basic API), They are phasing that out and won't accept anymore of those apps. You literally missed it by 5 or so months.